# Extending Application for global variables

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have been reading the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables) to setup a class to hold my global variables.
I have created the following class within my applications java file, my main activity follows it:

```
class GlobalStore extends Application {

    String str;

}

public class todo extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        GlobalStore appState = (GlobalStore) getApplicationContext();
        String tmpstr = appState.str;
    }
}
```

My manifest.xml file has the following tag:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="GlobalStore">
```

I'm pretty sure I followed the instructions correctly however my app force closes when it starts. Hopefully someone can point out what I have done wrong as I can't work it out.  Thanks.

Comment: A class name should by convention start with a capital letter. That means it should be `Todo` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing a dot.

It should be `.GlobalStore` as long as this class resides in the package set in the package attribute on the manifest node.

So it should look like this.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".GlobalStore">
```

Comment: Would you please post your `manifest` node definition as an edit on your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:name="GlobalStore"
```

This needs to be the full path including your package. ie

```
android:name="com.example.GlobalStore"
```

or whatever your package name is.

Comment: Well, that's not true. You can use, for instance, `android:name=".App"` ;) -1! When you edit it I will remove my downvote! haha just kidding... don't like downvotes XD Btw, I'm not kidding about the `.App` stuff.

Comment: You can't do that for the application node. You can do that for activity nodes but the application one has to be a full path.

Comment: I have tried both using the .GlobalStore and fullpath.globalstore but still getting fc's

Comment: @Crazyfool: So post your logcat

Comment: @falmarri sorry for the late response. Have you tried something like .AppName instead of the full path? I think you haven't because it works. If you are still in doubt I can prepare an example for you to learn from it :)

Comment: @Cristian: Maybe I have something confused, or something changed, because I thought it used to require that. I know there are cases where you need the full path. But I'm not sure what those are now.

Comment: @Falmarri: I think it is only when you use library components having another package path than your projects.